# Android Can i use resttemplate to serialise without sending request

Tags: android

I have a Json String available from WebView request

For consistency sake i want to use RestTemplate to deserialize the httpstring into object

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestTemnplate will always send a request the best way to be consistent for you is to use ObjectMapper
**Sample Code:**

```
public void convertJSONToProduct() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
    Product product = m.readValue(jsonString, Product.class);

}
```